# Stuff the snark?

Tags: word-meaning, slang

I just came across the phrase *stuff the snark* [on another SE site](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/45111/did-smallpox-emerge-in-1580#comment208602_45131):

> Can you please just stuff the snark?

Searching for this phrase I did not find any explanation (not even in the [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/)), only some more use cases like [here](https://books.google.nl/books?id=SHBFLVT4eqQC&pg=PT236&lpg=PT236&dq=%22stuff+the+snark%22&source=bl&ots=U6ewkW8O6f&sig=ACfU3U2t7knO3lsrJLlsFAjdbsgSjYzsZA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj4m4nyl4rlAhULjqQKHaDID4kQ6AEwAHoECAwQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22stuff%20the%20snark%22&f=false):

> “Kudos,” I said, trying to stuff the snark as far down as possible.

or [here](https://www.desmogblog.com/nrsp-not-ready-to-stop-perjuring):

> I’ve told you previously that I ride my bike, I eat mostly vegetarian, and use very little power, so you can stuff the snark if you’re trying to call me a hypocrite.

Maybe my initial assumption that it is a common or slang phrase (because it alliterates nicely) is incorrect, and I should just interpret it as to *suppress*  the *[snide remark](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snark)*?

Is there a relation with Lewis Carroll's [snark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snark_(Lewis_Carroll))?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*[Stuff it](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/stuff-it)* is a colloquial and rather rude way of telling someone to give up on something because you don't care about it. By itself, *stuff* in this context (and in your second example) means stifling, or suppressing some instinctive reaction.

*[Snark](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snark)* in this context seems unrelated to Lewis Carroll, and is just used to mean a sarcastic, snide attitude.

So you've interpreted the phrase correctly - it means that you're either trying to suppress the sarcastic tone or remarks, or telling someone to (the latter generally with a certain degree of irritation, telling them that you don't care about their snarky comments).

Comment: 'Snark' is mainly a US English term for sarcasm.

Comment: It's pretty common in the UK too (I blame TV! Damn all that communication!)

Comment: The trouble is that a certain amount of sarcasm is considered normal and even useful in British conversation, and, as far as I can tell, throughly despised by Americans in general, and 'snark' is a bad thing, I think.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Sarcasm, or snark, is also well-appreciated in America, though possibly in different ways or in different contexts. Someone telling another to “stuff it” clearly isn’t appreciating it. I think “rather rude” is an overstatement, myself, though. To my mind it’s a bit rude but rather less rude than, say, telling someone to “shut up.”